# Tkinter: Triggering python script with string input needed

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started learning programming with my Raspberry with python. I am currently trying to build program that integrating my 3 python script. One of them needed string input to work properly.

The code was:

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()

inputName = tk.Entry(window, width=30)
inputName.pack(pady=5)
inputName.insert(0, "")

window.title("System Access")
window.geometry('450x150')
window['bg'] = '#ffbf00'

def run_face_shot():
    os.system('python3 face_shot.py')
    name = inputName.get()

def run_train_model():
    os.system('python3 train_model.py')

def run_smart_office():
    os.system('python3 smart_office.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    btn = tk.Button(window, text="face shot", bg="grey", fg="white", command=run_face_shot)
    btn.pack(pady=2)
    btn = tk.Button(window, text="train model", bg="grey", fg="white", command=run_train_model)
    btn.pack(pady=7)
    btn = tk.Button(window, text="smart office", bg="grey", fg="white", command=run_smart_office)
    btn.pack(pady=5)
```

And the error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_shot.py", line 35, in <module>
    img_name = "dataset/"+ name +"/image_{}.jpg".format(img_counter)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

For my understanding I already have `name` in my gui program in `name = inputName.get()`
Which part of my code is wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit..

After I change the import line to `from gui_program import name` instead of `import gui_program`

The error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_shot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from test_gui import name
ImportError: cannot import name 'name' from 'test_gui' (/home/pi/myproject/../gui_program.py)
```

Edit again..

After I put `name = inputName.get()` below line `inputName.insert(0, "")`.
The code works, but the entered `name` does nothing. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `name` is a local variable inside `run_face_shot()`, so it will be destroyed once the function completes.

Comment: 'name' variable lives within this particular Python process, and `os.system` creates a new Python process; hence, the definition of `name` in this script will not be found in `face_shot.py`. When I said "process", I meant the process concept in the OS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)

Comment: but, I already do the import thing... is there any way to solve this

Comment: The code from the `face_shot.py` must run in the same file as the GUI. Import a function in there that works with the `name` variable to use this function when the user enters data. Or create a [CLI](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) from `face_shot.py` so you can pass arguments: `python3 face_shot.py --name name`.